# How to get UIImage from NSData SQLite blob

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uiimage, nsdata

I'm trying to get favicon of website, which I saved in sqlite.
When get NSData it's not nil, but when I trying convert to UIImage - UIImage in nil.
There is my code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) historyList{
    sqlite3 *db;

    thehistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSString *dbPath = strMessage;

        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        }


        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM HITSORY";
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
             NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }else{

            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                HistoryOBJ *author = [[HistoryOBJ alloc]init];//this is NSObject 
                author.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
                author.url = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
                NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStatement, 3) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStatement, 3)];
//imageData is saved favicon from website.


 if (imageData!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"THERE imageData IS NOT NIL");//There data is not nil.

                }
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

There I get my error, that `image` always is nil.

```
if (image==nil) {
                        NSLog(@"THERE image IS NIL");//There is my problem

                    }
                author.icon = image;//author.icon is UIImage variable

                [thehistory addObject:author];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return thehistory;
    }
}
```

What I'm missing there?

Comment: I'm guessing that the image was corrupted before you stored it.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like NSData required some decoding.
You can use [GMTBase.64](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMBase64.h?r=24) for encoding and decoding of data.

**Note: Don't write blob into sqlite. You can write data into Documents directory and save corresponding path into Sqlite. And while retreiving get path from sqlite and read data from document directory for corresponding path.**

Comment: A blob should be able to store image data without Base64 encoding.